# How can I get the "Edit Component's Name" window to show when I place a component?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I remember in Delphi 7, when you placed a component, a window would pop up allowing you to change the name of the component, like this

[image]

Is there a way I can enable this in Delphi 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That functionality is not built in to Delphi.  It is a third-party dialog provided by [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org), specifically their IDE Wizards (CnWizards) package.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I installed CnWizards, now how would I activate that specific functionality? edit: Nevermind I found it!