# How to edit component's name in Delphi (Short cut)

Tags: delphi, components, edit, shortcut

im new to Delphi and i just saw this 2do tutorial on Delphi. The thing is that i have read a lot of pages but i can't find what short cut to change a component's name (as the guy from the video does). It not a big deal, but it's breaking my head for a couple of days.

Thanks a lot!

You can see what i mean in the 28 sec of the video:

[Video tutorial #2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=K75URF7dNkk#t=27)

Comment: That guy is using a 3rd party extension from the CnWizard pack. Of course, you don't need it to change a component name. For you it's enough to go to the Object Inspector (`F11` key) and fill the `Name` property field.

Comment: http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a series of frames in an off-site video that may not exist for future users.

Comment: Also, see [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22073200) posted in a much better manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to get get used to standard workflow first:

To change components name you need to select it first, then go to `Object Inspector` frame (opened by `View` > `Object Inspector` or `F11`) and edit the `Name` field there. That's the components name.